# How to Create a Temboo SDK?

Tags: temboo

I'm interested in using Temboo on languages that are not yet supported; C, C++, .Net, others. How can this be done? Do you have an interface or pattern to follow?

Do I simply write methods similar to the descriptions here? https://www.temboo.com/arduino/technical-documentation

Am I correct that all SDKs ultimately issue the same/similar REST API calls so the challenge is to form the REST calls in a compatible manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question - thanks for asking. I work at Temboo.

We don't currently have an interface and set of guidelines that third parties can use to create Temboo SDKs. That said, you can call our REST API directly if you want to use Temboo from a language that we don't yet have an SDK for.

To get started, I recommend checking out this **[short video](https://temboo.com/videos#restapi)** that explains how to quickly get up and running with our REST API.

If you need more detail, here are some more helpful resources:

- [Temboo REST API Basics](http://support.temboo.com/entries/20155518-temboo-rest-api-basics)
- [Making Temboo REST API Requests](http://support.temboo.com/entries/20157291-making-temboo-rest-api-requests)
- [Temboo REST API Method Reference](http://support.temboo.com/entries/20157396-temboo-rest-api-method-reference)

Please don't hesitate to let me know if you have any questions as you get started - we're always happy to help.